# Unable to uninstall software installed using Wix MSI installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I used the Wix tool in Visual Studio 2015 to generate an msi in a custom directory - not in Program Files. The software got installed alright (only for current user) but I am unable to uninstall it.

The error shown is: `The specified path 'H:\Config.Msi\' is unavailable.`

However, a folder with name exists at the specified path. Also, the uninstallation succeeds when I delete the contents of the folder created by the installer.

Any ideas on how I can get the software to uninstall cleanly?

Comment: Is `H:` your system drive? Can we see the WiX source file for this project? Just edit your question please (do not add an answer).

Comment: No, `H:` is not my system drive. In fact, it is a virtual drive. Overriding TARGETDIR did the trick for me. It did throw a warning, though. Thanks, @SteinAsmul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the referenced path `H:` was a virtual drive that caused the error. Mapping `TARGETDIR` to reference the correct path was a work-around. For my use case, this was sufficient.

Comment: What do you mean with "mapping TARGETDIR to reference the correct path"? I have the same issue with python installed on a virtual K: drive which is mapped to a directory inside my homedir. I used mapping k: to shorten the path, since not all development tools support filenames with long paths under Windows.

Comment: From what I recollect, I think I had to set TARGETDIR to the actual path instead of just H:

Comment: Is TARGETDIR meant to be an environment variable? Or some property in a configuration file or windows registry? Sorry for asking again, as I am still unclear where shall I find this value.